# SQL String, TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

I tried to write a SQL in python, I always get the erorr

```
v1 = 'abc'
v2 = 'def'

name =  """
   fulfillment_week BETWEEN STRFTIME_USEC(DATE_ADD(%(v1)s, -34, "DAY"), '%Y-%m-%d')
      AND STRFTIME_USEC(DATE_ADD(%(v2)s, -6, "DAY"), '%Y-%m-%d')
""" % {'v1': v1, 'v2':v2}
```

when I run it, I always get

Comment: How many times does % appear? More than you make it happy for.

Comment: You should find a new database tutorial, preferably one that shows how to use parametrized queries.

Comment: And really, it's a pretty poor idea to use `%` based string substitutions in python when `%` is also the `LIKE` wildcard. You should use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead. But parameterized queries will also help solve that problem.

Comment: similar query I made it to work, just not sure what is difference between this one and the one that is working.

Comment: this is the working one.      WHERE (fulfillment_date >= "%(fulfillment_start_date)s" AND
            fulfillment_date <= "%(fulfillment_end_date)s")
            AND is_test_readable = "No"
  """ % {'fulfillment_start_date': fulfillment_start_date,
         'fulfillment_end_date': fulfillment_end_date}